# VHDL: ADC interfacing code doesn't work on the fpga kit, gives good simulation results

Tags: vhdl

I'm running my first VHDL code on FPGA kit. I've a simple external ADC (AD574A) which is to be interfaced with the FPGA kit. The code I've pasted below looks to give good results in simulation, but in the kit nothing at all works properly. The first process in the code (process(clk)) reduces the clock frequency by finite times. And the low frequency square wave that is generated is used to drive the second process(PROCESS (rst, clk_out)). clk_out is defined as a buffer in the program. So kindly someone let me know if this process of driving two processes with different clock sources is correct or not? I understand that this is where the problem lies,because though the two sections simulates correctly,but in the kit the first process works,the second doesn't.

```
library IEEE;    
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;    
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;    
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity newADC is    
port ( clk: in std_logic;    
       rst: in std_logic;    
       R_C: buffer std_logic;  
       clk_out : buffer  STD_LOGIC;     
       STS: in std_logic;
       data: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
       data_out: out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
     );
end newADC;

architecture Behavioral of newADC is        
    signal temp: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):=(others => '0');
    signal i: integer range 0 to 2:=0;
    signal j: integer range 0 to 10:=0;
    TYPE state IS (reading, converting);
    SIGNAL pr_state, nx_state: state;
    begin
    ----------------reduce clock frequency-------------------------
        PROCESS (clk)
        VARIABLE count_clk : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 10;
        BEGIN
            IF (clk'EVENT AND clk='1') THEN
                count_clk := count_clk + 1;
                IF (count_clk = 7 ) THEN                  -------- clk_out time period=  
                    clk_out <= NOT clk_out;                -------- clk*count*2
                    count_clk := 0;                        -------- board 'clk' is 40MHz/25ns time period
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END PROCESS;
----- Synchronous section: ----------------------------------------------
        PROCESS (rst, clk_out)      
        BEGIN
            IF (rst='1') THEN
                pr_state <= reading;
            ELSIF (clk_out'EVENT AND clk_out='1') THEN
                pr_state <= nx_state;
            END IF;
        END PROCESS;
---------- Cmbinational section: ------------------------------------------
        PROCESS (clk_out,STS,data,pr_state)         
        BEGIN
            CASE pr_state IS
                    WHEN reading =>
                    temp <= data;                   
                    case i is
                        when 0=> R_C <= '1';
                        when 1=> R_C <= '0';
                        when 2=> R_C <= '1';
                    end case;   
                    i <= i+1;
                    if (i = 3)then
                        i <= 0;
                    end if;             
                    IF (STS='1') THEN nx_state <= converting;
                    ELSE nx_state <= reading;
                    END IF;
                WHEN converting =>                  
                    R_C <= '1';
                    IF (STS='0') THEN nx_state <= reading;
                    ELSE nx_state <= converting;
                    END IF;
            END CASE;
        data_out <= temp;
        END PROCESS;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
end Behavioral;
```

Looking forward to this much needed help-
By-Tapabrata Sen

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be care full with clocks. Using multiple clocks is something you can do when you are more familiar with hardware designs.

Use a clock enable instead, also I would prefer synchronous resets.

```
   PROCESS (clk)
    VARIABLE count_clk : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 10;
    BEGIN
        IF (clk'EVENT AND clk='1') THEN
            count_clk := count_clk + 1;
            clk_en <= '0';
            IF (count_clk = 7 ) THEN                  -------- clk_out time period=  
                clk_en <= '1';                -------- clk*count*2
                count_clk := 0;                        -------- 
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
    PROCESS (clk)      
    BEGIN
        IF (rising_edge(clk)) THEN
            IF (rst='1') THEN
                pr_state <= reading;
            ELSIF (clk_en='1') THEN;
                pr_state <= nx_state;
            END IF
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
```

Also your sensitivity list in the last process is wrong all changing inputs to your process must be part of the sensitivity list and the clk_out should not be there

Answer (score 0):

`i` isn't in the sensitivity list for the combinational section process. `clk_out` doesn't appear to be necessary in it's sensitivity list as written.

`i` is incremented on transition of `pr_state` and could be susceptible to combinatorial/path delays, you likely want to clock it with `clk_out`.  i is incremented any time there's an event on any signal in the sensitivity list, essentially both edges of `clk_out`, any change in `data`, or `pr_state`. This likely accounts for simulation and implementation performance differences.

R_C is the AD754A Read_Convert, and it probably misbehaves.  You should have seen at least a warning message during synthesis about how the `i` counter is clocked.  If I had to hazard a guess without seeing your synthesis reports I'd bet R_C is static (a '1'). If you have a scope check out what's happening at the AD754A.

There may be other issues with your VHDL design specification,  `j` isn't assigned anywhere, you have two use clauses that aren't needed:

```
-- use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

It seems counter-intuitive to increment the `i` counter in a process you're claiming is purely combinatorial. It may be ripe for a separate process or get rid of the claim in the comment.

I haven't tried running a 'patched' version with an `i` counter fix.  It'd require a testbench to determine what you consider is okay to begin with.

The datasheet is readily available for those interested in doing so, See  the [AD574A (Rev. B)](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD574A.pdf) datasheet.